# Can uTorrent auto re-order torrents (for maximum bandwidth utilization)?

Tags: utorrent

How can I automatically change download priority of torrents based on certain criteria?

For example, I have 12 torrents queued up right now. And I have configured uTorrent to keep a maximum of 4 torrents active due to my bandwidth.

Now, I want to automatically change the download order of torrents in certain intervals, based first on seed/peer ratio and then on number of seeds(in case of a conflict).

The reason I want to do this is to make most out of bandwidth available to me.

Is this possible? (honestly, I don't think it is possible)

I am okay to switch to some other torrent client if required.

Comment: You can set maximum download of torrent to 1-2 for use full bandwidth and queue option will do the rest. Otherwise this is not possible not yet.

Comment: If not with uTorrent, any other client that runs on windows?

Comment: Well, I have used some and AFAIK there is no one can, but you can try with `vuze` because I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: okay..
i'll try vuze.

Comment: The closest you can come with µTorrent (for now?) is to assign bandwidth priority (right-click->*Bandwidth Allocation*), but that is a simple, static assignment. Of course you can also assign upload and download settings per-torrent, so between the two options, you may be able to sort of hack out what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use some of the advanced options to optimize your queue. This is from the uTorrent Manual

> queue.dont_count_slow_dl: Enabling this option tells BitTorrent to
>   ignore slow downloading torrent jobs as part of the queue. If a
>   torrent job is downloading at less than the value specified by
>   queue.slow_dl_threshold, it will not prevent the next item in the
>   queue from starting.

So enable `queue.dont_count_slow_dl` and set the `queue.slow_dl_threshold` to an appropriate value. I think the number is Bps(Bytes per sec). This will optimize your queue with 4(your active downloads limit) torrents that download at a decent speed even if there are other slower ones in the queue. Make sure you dont set `queue.slow_dl_threshold` too high or you will have too many active downloads downloading at slow rates.

Hope this helps out in optimizing your bandwidth utilization.

Comment: nice...finally something that is useful..i will check it asap.

Comment: it seems this is all that can be done...

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't think it is possible too.

You have 12 torrents and 4 of them are active. That means other 8 torrents are inactive. How can a INACTIVE torrent know how many seeds it has? So, first of all, I think, you should active all your torrents and just limit the max connections of uTorrent.

Or you can try rtorrent which allows you to customize by your own scripts under certain conditions.

Comment: You see, by inactive, I don't mean they are stopped. Instead, they are queued. So, when one of first 4 torrents is completed, fifth one automatically starts downloading(its in-built feature of uTorrent).

I cannot keep all the torrents active because then all will get downloaded in small portions...