# Is there a Torrent client for Windows with scripting/macros support?

Tags: bittorrent

Is there any torrent client for windows that allows scripting or macros?

I believe [Transmission allows scripting](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Scripts), but it doesn't run on Windows.

This question has actually arisen from [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/431417/utorrent-torrent-auto-re-orderfor-maximum-bandwidth-utilization) of mine.

Comment: scripting column should be added to the wikipedia page under "Features"...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients

Comment: You could run a virtual machine with Linux and rTorrent/Transmission/etc.

Comment: that's a fairly lengthy and heavy solution..

Answer (score 1):

From the torrent clients on Window that I know, [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) comes closest to this.

Deluge allows you to write and install [plugins](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Development/1.3/Plugin). A plugin's core is written in Python.

Also, the [Deluge Console](http://whatbox.ca/wiki/Deluge_Console_Documentation) supports a variety of commands that can be executed using pretty much every scripting language there is.